# How to display count information to page

Tags: php, sql, count, output

I have created a query to select and count specific fields from one table and the corrisponding name from another table the query works when i run it in the sql on localhost but cant work out how to display the result to the page

e.g

```
Item name1 - count 
tiem name2 - count
```

here is the query

```
 $objects->connect();

// Count Query
    $countQuery = 'SELECT a.`subId`, b.`subId`, b.`subTitle`, COUNT(a.`subId`) FROM `tbl_list`a, `tbl_subs`b WHERE a.`subId` = b.`subId` GROUP BY a.`subId`';

//Run the query
$objects->query($countQuery);
```

how would i display the result to the page

Comment: Use alias: "COUNT(a.`subId`) as cnt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your function `$objects->query($countQuery);` must return the result array which you can get like this:

```
$result = $objects->query($countQuery);
```

and then apply loop to  `$result;`

Yes add `COUNT(a.subId) as cnt` as well and then like `echo $result[0]->cnt;`
depends upon your return array format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply so do you mean something like

Comment: while($row = $objects->result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
         $subOutput .= '<p>' . $row['subTitle'] . ' ' . $row['count'] . '</p>';
    }

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help it is working now appreciate the assistance